# Solving inequalities involving square roots

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

What is the correct way to solve inequalities like $\sqrt {x+2}>x $   ?

I deduced that $x$ must be greater than$-2$ and also on squaring I get $-1 \leq x \leq 2$ but even on combining these two I'm not getting the correct answer.What am I missing?

Comment: What is the correct answer,please?

Comment: -2 to 2 is the answer...

Comment: Yeah...I was thinking of putting the answer but I was late...nevertheless,The answer by @C. Dubussy must solve your problem..:-)..

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use: $$\sqrt{f(x)}>g(x) \Leftrightarrow$$

$\Leftrightarrow \begin{cases}
g(x)<0\\
f(x)\ge0\end{cases}$
or
$\begin{cases}
g(x)\ge0\\
f(x)>\left(g(x)\right)^2
\end{cases}$

> !$$\sqrt{x+2}>x$$
>
> !Case 1) $$\begin{cases}
> x<0\\
> x+2\ge0\end{cases}$$
>
> !Case 2) $$\begin{cases}
> x\ge0\\
> x+2>\left(x \right)^2
> \end{cases}$$

Answer (score 8):

First note that $x$ must be greater than $-2$, because of the square root. Then you have two cases :

If $x \in [-2,0[$ the inequality is true since a square root is positive.

If $x \in [0,+\infty)$, then both sides are positive and you can square it to obtain the equivalent inequation $$x+2 > x^2.$$ That is $$x^2-x-2 < 0.$$ The discriminant here is $9$ and you can hence deduce the factorisation $$(x-2)(x+1) <0.$$ Then do a sign table with the two factors to conclude.

Answer (score 2):

Observe if $-2 \leq x \leq 0$, the inequality holds trivially. If $x > 0$, square both sides to get an equivalent one: $x+2 > x^2 \iff x^2 -x - 2 < 0\iff (x-2)(x+1) < 0\iff -1 <x < 2\implies -2 \leq x < 2$

Answer (score 2):

Beware that

$$a>b$$ does not imply $$a^2>b^2.$$

Indeed,

$$a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)>0$$ is equivalent to $a-b>0$ only when $a+b>0$, otherwise the inequality gets reversed.